# How to draw circles on button click at a certain location?

Tags: java, android

I am pretty new to Android so I apologize ahead of time if I am missing something, but my problem is that I am trying to draw a circle at a certain location everytime I click on the screen.

I have tried logging and it does return an int where it matches my if statement but nothing gets drawn.

```
 public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                drawCirc = true;
                xTouch = event.getX();
                Log.d("keyboard", "xpos" + xTouch);
                yTouch = event.getY();
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                drawCirc = false;
        }
        return true;
    }


    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        if(drawCirc) {
            if (xTouch < 150 && xTouch>0) {
                    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
                    canvas.drawCircle(150, 500, 100, paint);
                    isPlayer1 = false;
                    invalidate();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Call invalidate inside your touch event listener and not in onDraw

Comment: Okay that you it works now!

Comment: @Javanator could OP set `drawCirc` to false inside `onDraw` before `invalidate()` to avoid recursive calls?

Comment: @Javanator Another quick question, would it be possible to draw multiple circles using this way? Whenever I click it replaces the circle.

Comment: @AyeYo, with your code above, there will be only 1 circle being drawn, because each time you click, you `ACTION_DOWN` to draw and show circle, then `ACTION_UP` hides the circle you had drawn. If you want to have multiple circle be be shown, first you'll want to add a `pointsList` to record all the points you want to draw circle at, when action_down add an point to list, remove it when action_up; then in your `onDraw`, loop the list and draw circles with the points; BTW, you'd better to have an animator or delay when hiding the circle when `ACTION_UP`, in this way user will see multi-circles

Comment: @Doc I don't think that works, because without triggering `invalidate` in on touch listener there is no chance to call `onDraw` when user clicking the view. But indeed, the above code will have `overdraw` issue as `invalidate` within `onDraw` will trigger another `draw`, yes that set it as false resolves the issue.

Comment: @AyeYo check this also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3406910/efficient-2d-drawing-in-android/3408641#3408641

Comment: @AyeYo check this also. you can save previous draw as a bitmap draw that on canvas and draw other circles on touch https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24376122/how-to-save-objects-previously-drawn-to-the-canvas-on-a-redraw. This is more efficient that redrawing all circles by remembering all points

Answer (score 1):

@Javanator is right, you should do `invalidate` in touch listener.

Meanwhile, you can try out the code below, which adds animation when circle being drawn.

```java
Paint paint = new Paint();

{
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
}

// The radius of the circle you want to draw
// 0 by default
private int radius = 0;

// The animator to animate circle drawing
private ObjectAnimator radiusAnimator;

public void setRadius(int newRadius) {
    this.radius = newRadius;
    this.invalidate();
}

private void showCircle(boolean show) {
    ObjectAnimator animator = this.getRadiusAnimator();
    if (show) {
        animator.start();
    } else {
        animator.reverse();
    }
}

private ObjectAnimator getRadiusAnimator() {
    if (this.radiusAnimator == null) {
        this.radiusAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(this, "radius", 0, 100);
    }
    return this.radiusAnimator;
}


public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            // drawCirc = true;
            xTouch = event.getX();
            Log.d("keyboard", "xpos" + xTouch);
            yTouch = event.getY();
            showCircle(true);
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            // drawCirc = false;
            showCircle(false);
    }
    return true;
}


public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    if (xTouch < 150 && xTouch > 0) {
        canvas.drawCircle(xTouch, yTouch, radius, paint);
    }
    /*
    if(drawCirc) {
        if (xTouch < 150 && xTouch>0) {
                paint.setColor(Color.RED);
                canvas.drawCircle(150, 500, 100, paint);
                isPlayer1 = false;
                invalidate();
    */            
 }
```

Comment: avoid creating paint object in ondraw as it is called every time you call invalidate to refresh. You could initialize once

Comment: @Raghunandan you're correct I didn't notice that in his code. Updated the code

Answer (score 0):

```
public class CustomView extends View {
boolean drawCirc;
float xTouch;
boolean isPlayer1;
float yTouch;
public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        drawCirc=true;
        xTouch = event.getX();
        yTouch = event.getY();
        invalidate();
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    if (drawCirc) {
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        canvas.drawCircle(xTouch, yTouch, 100, paint);
        isPlayer1 = false;
        invalidate();
    }
}}
```

I have solved your functionality and Implemented sample code. I have checked it and it's working and you have not put a code in onTouch Listener that's why it's not worked but now I have solved. if you want area limit then put your`if (xTouch < 150 && xTouch>0)`